# typedef INT_PTR and LONG_PTR issues

Tags: sdk, typedef

I read some code and jump to windows sdk file :c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\platformsdk\include\basetsd.h

```
typedef _W64 int INT_PTR, *PINT_PTR;
typedef _W64 unsigned int UINT_PTR, *PUINT_PTR;

typedef _W64 long LONG_PTR, *PLONG_PTR;
typedef _W64 unsigned long ULONG_PTR, *PULONG_PTR;

#define __int3264   __int32
```

I　googled and find that the INT_PTR mean one int which is equal in size to a pointer.
but what the LONG_PTR mean?  one long which is equal in size to a pointer. But does not a long and int different size?

Answer (score 2):

These macros are useful for making Win32 code portable so it builds in both 32-bit and 64-bit mode. In some cases, they also indicate that a variable might contain either a number or a pointer.

The purpose of `INT_PTR` and `LONG_PTR` is to replace declarations of `int` and `long` that are actually being used to hold a pointer (generally a bad thing, but old code I've encountered sometimes overloads such fields and uses them to contain sentinel integers like 0 and -1, or a real pointer). For example, in Win32 code, `int`, `long`, and `char *` are all 4 bytes.  In Win64 code, `int` and `long` are still 4 bytes, but `char *` is 8 bytes; if a `char *` is stored in an int using a C-style cast, it will be silently truncated.

`INT_PTR` and `LONG_PTR` (and their unsigned variants) are different and named as they are to make it easier to fix such usages as they're guaranteed to fit either an `int` or `long`, or a pointer.  If you have an `int`, replace it with `INT_PTR`; `unsigned int` should be replaced with `UINT_PTR`, `long` should be replaced with `LONG_PTR`, etc.  That sort of preserves the original semantics  while allocating enough storage for either type (int, long, pointer...).

Example:

```
int iptr = (int) pData;   // bad
```

could be

```
INT_PTR iptr = (INT_PTR) pData;     // better
```

And this will work on both x86 and x64 compilations.

Note that you **must change the cast** for pointers to avoid potential truncation. Fortunately, Visual Studio 2015 will warn you if you don't.

Since Windows `HANDLE` types are now defined as pointers, the same applies to them. Note, however, that handles may still be safely truncated to fit in 4 bytes, even in 64-bit mode.  This is not true for actual pointers.